# How to buld slider without sliding function in flutter

Tags: flutter, slider

I want to builder slider bar(similar to SleekCircularSlider) exactly like this in flutter

[image: I want to builder slider bar(similar to SleekCircularSlider) exactly like this in flutter]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the flutter in-built `Slider` widget as you want. Find the code snippets below.

```
final double sliderValue = 90.0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        width: 350,
        height: 350,
        child: SliderTheme(
          data: SliderThemeData(
            overlayColor: Colors.transparent,
            thumbShape: SliderComponentShape.noThumb,
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  Text('HTML'),
                  Text(sliderValue.toInt().toString() + '%')
                ],
              ),
              Slider(
                  value: 90,
                  min: 0.0,
                  max: 100.0,
                  divisions: 100,
                  mouseCursor: MouseCursor.uncontrolled,
                  onChanged: (double value) {}),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
final  double value = 0.9;

Container(
          color: Colors.black,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'html',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    '$value%',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              LinearProgressIndicator(
                value: 0.9,
                color: Colors.yellow,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: but how can we add animation to it, just like SleekCircularSlider have in default

Comment: use setState or  State management listen when value  var change